# Javascript Fading out/in on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, transition

I want to have a fixed nav which fades out when the mouse isn't moving and fades back in when it does.

I've came across [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434004/navbar-that-appears-when-mouse-moves-and-disappears-when-still) **which does the job** but the problem is that it uses `visibility` and I want to use `opacity` that way I can make it fade in and out with a transition `transition: all .4s ease-in-out;`

```js
$("#fp-nav").style.opacity = "0";

$("html").mousemove(function(event) {
  $("#fp-nav").style.opacity = "1";

  myStopFunction();
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#fp-nav").style.opacity = "0";
  }, 1000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  if (typeof myVar != 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
  }
}
```

```css
#fp-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fp-nav">
  Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world
</div>
```

Or am I supposed to use `fp-nav.style.opacity = "0";` instead of  `$("#fp-nav").style.opacity = "0";`

Comment: Can you get a working bin or pen of this up so people can play around with it?

Comment: @Panic `$(#fp-nav)` returns the match in a jQuery object with `style` not being a property. Have you tried `fp-nav.style`? or `$("#fp-nav")[0].style...`

Comment: @Fran Yes that was stupid to not see that it's formatted for jquery, but someone already posted a solution, thanks anyways for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `.hide()` and `.show()` by your own css code to visually hide the bar: `hide` becomes `css("opacity", 0)` and `show` becomes `css("opacity", 1)`.

Then, you add a transition to your bar:

```
.navbar {
   transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
};
```

```js
$("div").css("opacity", 0);

$("html").mousemove(function( event ) {
    $("div").css("opacity", 1);
    
    myStopFunction();
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div").css("opacity", 0);
    }, 1000);
}
function myStopFunction() {
    if(typeof myVar != 'undefined'){
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>navbar</div>
```

It might be nice to let the css define how you want to hide/show via an additional class. You can then, for example, use `addClass("is-hidden")` and `removeClass("is-hidden")`:

```js
var hiddenClass = "is-hidden";
var customHide = function($el) {
  $el.addClass(hiddenClass);
} 

var customShow = function($el) {
  $el.removeClass(hiddenClass);
} 

customHide($("div"));

$("html").mousemove(function( event ) {
    customShow($("div"));
    
    myStopFunction();
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){
        customHide($("div"));
    }, 1000);
}
function myStopFunction() {
    if(typeof myVar != 'undefined'){
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
}
```

```css
/* CSS now determines how we want to hide our bar */

div {
  position: relative;
  background: green;

  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}

div.is-hidden {
  transform: translateY(-160%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>navbar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(){
 $('#nav').addClass('shown');
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#nav').removeClass('shown');
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
#nav {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#nav.shown {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
</div>
```

Here's my go:

Obviously, edit the timings and opacity as needed. The animations themselves are pure CSS, and JS is just used to add/remove a class from the nav.